# output of python in php without arrays

Tags: php

I have tried

```
$output = null;
exec('python hyp.py' $output);
echo var_export($output, TRUE);
```

and

```
var_dump($output);
```

Both is working perfectly. The output I get is

```
array(0 => 'first line output', 1 => 'second line output',)
```

I need a way to output the python file without showing the arrays and arrows in between each line of output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop trough the output array and then echo each line:

```
$output = null;
exec('python hyp.py' $output);

if($output)
  foreach($output as $line)
    echo $line;
```

Comment: Please consider adding a bit of explaining to the code. Don't forget that this site is viewed, not only by the OP, but by users coming from Google!

Comment: I added some clarification :)

Answer (score 2):

You can manipulate the array - or just [use the right function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php):

```
$completeOutputAsString = shell_exec('python hyp.py');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of dumping the variable, you simply loop through it using [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach ($output as $value) {
    echo $value . "<br />";
}
```

Or do what you want with the array/value.  This is just an example.